# Streaming Files in a folder

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm moving the streaming app from flume to kafka.
I need help since I'm new to kafka.

I've a windows machine on which CSV Files are continously being generated by IOT sensors at a particular location say D:/Folder.
I want to transfer it to a hadoop cluster.

1) Do I need a kafka cluster/brokers in between transferring log files or can I directly transfer from my windows machine to hadoop linux machine?

2) Can I just install kafka on windows and hadoop linux machine and  then I  directly publish my CSV files to a kafka topic created on hadoop machine.
I will run a consumer on hadoop machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use a kafka consumer to get files and put it on HDFS. You need a producer to send the files on your queue and a consumer to do what you want with them.

The producer can be run in Windows and need tu use kafka client api.

The consumer must run on the HDFS. You need to install kafka on your cluster, configure it etc... depends of your Hadoop distribution.

Comment: there are millions of small files being generated daily in the folder. And i want to spool the folder with kafka for any new files.

Comment: So use a kafka consumer to get files and put it on HDFS. You need a producer to send the files on your queue and a consumer to do what you want with them.

The producer can be run in Windows and need tu use kafka client api.

The consumer must run on the HDFS. You need to install kafka on your cluster, configure it etc... depends of your Hadoop distribution.

I edit my post, I didn't well understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Franck. I want to pull records from my kafka topic say swipe_records to HDFS path in every 60 seconds. I guess you already have implemented it. Can you provide me some insights or references as to how you achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a kafka cluster/brokers in between transferring log files

If you want to use Kafka, then yes, you need an actual cluster.

> can I directly transfer from my windows machine to hadoop linux machine?

Sure. Use Flume, Spark, Flink, NiFi, etc. Kafka is not necessary

> Can I just install kafka on windows and hadoop linux machine and then I directly publish my CSV files to a kafka topic created on hadoop machine

You wouldn't install Kafka for a producer client. You'd download the libraries and use them to publish messages. Feel free to install Kafka on the Hadoop nodes, but they should really be on independent hardware